# How to search for youtube channels in a given country

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was wondering if there is a way for **search for YouTube channels in a specific country**?

I need to find channels in Germany, so i was trying with regionCode=DE, but it doesn't seem to work:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search

I used:

- part=snippet
- type=channel
- regionCode=DE

Do you have another ideas how to search for channels from specific country ?

Thanks in advance for reply!

Robert

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12569824/4092887) and I tested using the `gl=DE` parameter in the URL. Example: `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=c%23&gl=DE` but I got the same results that I previously saw before add this parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Mauricio. Will give it a try!