# How can I search the channel in a specific country using the YouTube API 3.0?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use the url to search channels in a specific country like this *https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=8&order=viewCount&q=news&type=channel&regionCode=US&key=API-Key*.

But when i changed the regionCode parameter to IT(italy) or any other one,the search result is always identical.So the search result is not changed with the regionCode.

How can I search the channel by country using the YouTube API 3.0,thanks.

Comment: any updates on this ? ( and the location & location radius only work for video search & returns error for channel search )

Answer (score 3):

I also try to search channel with the optional parameter `regionCode`, and it seems that this parameter is not to filter the results base on the country code of a Country. I found in this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540609/how-to-find-videos-by-country-and-keyword) that the region parameter only applies to movie charts, and is not something that works as a parameter for general searches.

So the only possible parameter that I think you can use to filter the results of YouTube API in a specific country or place is by using the parameter [`location`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#location).

The `location` parameter, in conjunction with the `locationRadius` parameter, defines a circular geographic area and also restricts a search to videos that specify, in their metadata, a geographic location that falls within that area. The parameter value is a string that specifies latitude/longitude coordinates e.g. (37.42307,-122.08427).

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to solve this problem. I tried location with locationRadius, but second parameter is limited to 1000km, so, I cant find all videos from Russian Federation or USA using that option and 1 api request.
Also, that api request **performs slow** for understandable reason.